# Use of an internal webservice instead of direct access to database

Tags: sql-server, wcf, firewall

I'm designing various parts of a network. My current thought on design for future software projects:

Webserver in a DMZ. This webserver has a hole punched through the firewall (On the sql port) to talk to an    MSSQL database which is internal for all data management.

Question: Instead of having a hole in the firewall to talk to the database server, would it be better / more secure to have an internal web server hosting web services that applications in the DMZ can consume, with the database logic behind the web service ( a hole punched to talk to that webserver only. )

A webservices implementation would allow only one place for updating any API changes - which is why I'm considering it - though it would likely be slower than direct database and query access.

Any thoughts as to which is better?

EDIT: Realized that unless I put all application/business logic in the application layer, I would still need a hole punched into the firewall for sql. Since I want an added layer only for the API functions (those that affect all applications - such as "GetEmployeeByName"), I'd still need access to the DB from the DMZ...

Leaning toward the best answer being: Internal web service API server hosting web services - those are consumable by either all web servers in the DMZ, or via a proxy server in the DMZ. (so only one server needs an ssl port through firewall.)    (And of course all internal servers would have access.)

Comment: Tiers need not correspond to separate machines. If you design your application properly, it won't matter whether the "app tier" is on the same machine or not, scaled out through web services, or not.

Comment: If I choose one or the other, direct db access, or an application tier (firewall rule for only one or the other), all logic requiring a database would have to be on a separate server since the only database access is on the other side of the firewall.

Comment: That's an implementation decision, not a design decision. Design your application so that either implementation can work without requiring a rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many discussions about when three-tier architecture is a better model ([here's one](http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2012/07/20/when_do_you_need_a_3_tier_architecture.html)).  You should be able to find more on Google.

Short answer:  It's probably better to go with the app-tier service, if security and scalability are your goals.  Be sure to focus on [defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29) as you develop all tiers and layers.

Long answer:  It depends on your needs.

Edit in response to your edit:  I would recommend putting most of your business logic in the app tier anyway, if it makes sense to do that.  Your web server(s) should primarily be presentation.
Regardless of where you put the business logic, though, you should put all data access into the service - the web tier should only talk to the app tier.

[Here](http://www.google.com/search?q=when+is+three-tier+architecture+better&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active)'s a beginning search to dig into the three-tier aspect.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10746/Dude-where-s-my-business-logic)'s a decent introduction for splitting of tiers and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you. It is up to you, but if you have opinions, I wouldn't mind them based on the edit I put.

Your linked articles were helpful, as googling was not working for me (I didn't really know what to search for)

Comment: @DFTR:  Edited to respond to your further questions.

Comment: I'm contemplating the complexity, from having to write the services and write code to consume them, and request time by having an entire business layer behind a firewall in the form of web services. I'll have to build some tests and see what I like - Either way, Thank you for your most helpful answers.

Comment: @DFTR: I've typically found that throwing up a WCF service and a client for it is pretty quick. Good luck!